# Refresh problems with Silverlight and Chrome

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, silverlight-4.0

On a windows 7, visual studio 2010, I can't get my silverlight app to refresh in Chrome 10.0.648.204. Even when closing the tab displaying the app. Using internet explorer 8 I have no problems. Heelp I prefer using Chrome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short term solution is to clear Chrome's cache after you deploy a new xap. A slightly longer solution can be found here:

[Prevent your silverlight xap file from caching in your browser.](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2011/01/06/prevent-your-silverlight-xap-file-from-caching-in-your-browser.aspx)

Comment: I tried adding a ?refresh=244  argument to try tricking it into refreshing, alas with no effect

Comment: You may still need to clear the cache and restart your debugging process to get it to kick in.

Comment: I guess there is some sort of timeout since my app from yesterday did not survive for today. I'm just worried about the end user having to know he should clear his cache because I upgraded my app :(

Comment: In that case, try this: http://dotnetefectivecoding.blogspot.com/2010/02/automatically-downalod-latest-xap-file.html - You can set it up to retrieve the latest xap file. It's VB but you should still be able to discern a C# version with some luck heh